# I want to display a dynamic form only when there are values for that id as below?How can i approach it?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms

[image]I have object coming from backend,like this template_parameter: "namespace,resources", and for some ids it is template_parameter: "null". When there are some values in the template_parameter: "namespace,resources", I wanted to display a form with those fileds. if it is null, i dont want to display, How can I approach this.I split values, But i am trying to write a code which only displays a form when it there are some values. Hope you understand my question. appreciate your help. Thank you.
Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="templateform">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ntw-pol-egren-podns"  class="bmd-label-floating">{{variable1}}<sup
        class="text-danger">*</sup>
        </label>
        
        <input  [(ngModel)]="namespace" formControlName="namespace" type="text" class="form-control" id="ntw-pol-egren-podns">
        
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.namespace.errors" class="error-feedback error">
            <p *ngIf="f.namespace.errors.required" class="text-danger">
                Namespace is required
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ntw-pol-egren-podns" class="bmd-label-floating">{{variable2}}<sup
        class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="resource" [(ngModel)]="resources"  id="ntw-pol-egren-podns">
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.resource.errors" class="error-feedback error">
            <p *ngIf="f.resource.errors.required" class="text-danger ">
                Resource is required
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button  (click)="sendclusteridApi()"  class="btn btn-primary px-3 py-2">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

ts:

```
changeSelection() {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {
        this.selectedItemsList.push(this.DisplayProductList[index])
        console.log(this.selectedItemsList,"sel")
        let splitstring = this.DisplayProductList[index].template_parameter
        console.log(splitstring,"df")
        let sepratedArray = splitstring.split(',');
        this.variable1 = sepratedArray[0];
        this.variable2 = sepratedArray[1];
        return product.isChecked;
    });
}
```

Comment: Inside changeSelection how you can access `this.DisplayProductList.template_parameter` like this.  It's a array?

Comment: share content inside `this.DisplayProductList`

Comment: Okay navnath,I will

Comment: I edited my above code,I am actually trying to put displayproductlist in the selectedItemlist.

Comment: Share sample data inside `this.DisplayProductList` array. for which you want to create `Form` for the values which are not null or empty

Comment: 65:
active: true
created_by: ""
created_date: "2021-08-19T05:25:13.708Z"
id: 2
label: "Disallow Default Namespace"
modified_by: ""
modified_date: "2021-08-19T05:25:13.708Z"
template_name: "disallow_default_namespace"
template_parameter: "namespace,resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create FormGroup :

```
 productFG: FormGroup;
```

Iterate through your array of `this.DisplayProductList` and create `FormGroup` for each Entry

```
const productFArray = this.DisplayProductList.map(obj =>
  this.createFormGroup(obj)
);

this.productFG = this.fb.group({
  policies: this.fb.array(productFArray)
});
```

creating `FormGroup`, dynamically create a control for `Id`, `label` and for `template_parameter` we will create nested `FormGroup` named `additionalParams`

```
private createFormGroup(obj): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [obj.id],
      label: [obj.label],
      additionalParams: this.formGroupByTemplate(obj.template_parameter)
    });
  }

  private formGroupByTemplate(template_parameter: string): FormGroup {
    const splitted = template_parameter.split(',');
    if (template_parameter == '') {
      return this.fb.group({});
    } else {
      const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
      splitted.forEach(val => formGroup.addControl(val, this.fb.control(null)));
      return formGroup;
    }
  }
```

Other helper getters

```
  get policiesFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.productFG.get('policies') as FormArray;
  }

  getGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
    return this.policiesFormArray.at(index) as FormGroup;
  }

  getTemplateFG(index: number): FormGroup {
    return this.getGroup(index).get('additionalParams') as FormGroup;
  }

  getFormGroupKeys(index): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.getTemplateFG(index).controls);
  }
```

In template : Used `getFormGroupKeys` to retrive `formControlName` from the `additionalParams` FormGroup.

```
<form [formGroup]="productFG">
  <div formArrayName="policies">
    <div *ngFor="let control of policiesFormArray.controls; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div> {{ "Id : "+ getGroup(i).get('id').value }} - {{ getGroup(i).get('label').value }} </div>
        <div formGroupName="additionalParams" *ngFor="let key of getFormGroupKeys(i);">
          {{ key }} : <input type="text" [formControlName]="key"><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wq3hxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)